# Doxygen using python not extracting method descriptions for files

Tags: python, documentation, doxygen

I am documenting a python project using doxygen. I created my config file, and set the In and out Directory, but that is all I really did. When I generate the documentation it extracts the class and class hierarchy, but for my modules with functions it does not.

As in, I have a .py file that has a main and a set of functions which I have documented in the correct comment syntax, but these functions are not represented in the documentation whatsoever. Why is this?

Comment: # If the EXTRACT_ALL tag is set to YES doxygen will assume all entities in
# documentation are documented, even if no documentation was available.
# Private class members and static file members will be hidden unless
# the EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC tags are set to YES

EXTRACT_ALL            = YES

# If the EXTRACT_PRIVATE tag is set to YES all private members of a class
# will be included in the documentation.

EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES

Comment: Changed "no" to yes. Problem solved... don't know how to close this question.

Comment: Colton, post your solution as an answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 3):

With a default doxygen configuration, module-level functions are only documented if the file or module they are in are also documented. For example:

```
##
# My function
#
def func():
    pass
```

Will not be documented unless the file is documented:

```
##
# @file
# File documentation
#
```

Or the module is documented:

```
##
# @package MyModule Module documentation
#
```

For more information on documenting Python code in Doxygen, see http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks.

Comment: Also note that you cannot document the file/module using Pythons `"""`, as Doxygen does not support special commands in those comments.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the official documentation, "special commands" are supported in docstrings. To do this the docstring must start with """!

Example:

```
def area(l, w):
    """! Calculate the area in sqm

    @param l length 
    @param w width
    @return area 

    @todo throw error if l<0 or w<0
    """
    return l*w
```